# Python LinearRegression ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I use this code to do `LinearRegression` :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

def calculate_Intercept_X_Variable():
    list_a=[['2018', '3', 'aa', 'aa', 93,1884.7746222667, 165.36153386251098], ['2018', '3', 'bb', 'bb', 62, 665.6392779848, 125.30386609565328], ['2018', '3', 'cc', 'cc', 89, 580.2259903521, 160.19280253775514]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_a)
    X = df.iloc[:, 5]
    y = df.iloc[:, 6]
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(X, y)

calculate_Intercept_X_Variable()
```

But the error message is:

> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
>   ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3]

Where is wrong?

How to modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From scikit-learn document, it says:

> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>   Training data
>
> y : array_like, shape (n_samples, n_targets)
>   Target values. Will be cast to X’s dtype if necessary

Problem is that right now X and y are 1D arrays.

```
X.shape, y.shape
# ((3,), (3,))
```

You should reshape your X and y:

```
X = X.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: X and y must 2d matrix?

Comment: @J.Show `fit` is expecting X and y to have shape of (n_samples, n_features), which means that even if you are using 1 field, it should have a shape of (3,1), not (3, ). I'll make some edit to explain further.

Comment: Only `X` needs to be 2-d. `y` can and should be 1-d here.